# Running pihole as a DHCP server stops working after a while

Tags: dhcp, pi-hole

I'm running pi-hole in a Proxmox container. I followed this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnFtWsZ8IP0&t=718s&ab_channel=CraftComputing In it I set custom DNS in PiHole - 127.0.0.1#5335. I have a tp-link router AC1750. After doing that I went to the router and disabled the DHCP server and then rebooted. I enabled DHCP server in pi-hole then updated gravity in pihole. I did ipconfig/all and verified that pi hole is now is m DHCP server. Everything works fine for around 1 hour then it stops working and now I do not have access to the internet and I have to go back to using the DHCP server in my router.

I tried to give the pi-hole a reserved ip but still the same issue. It runs just fine for a while then it stops. Any idea what's going on here. I also have a very long ADlist blocked using https://firebog.net/. I can not think about anything that cause this issue. Help!

Answer (score 0):

I've been running Pi-hole as my DHCP for years, and suddenly, I started experiencing disconnect issues three days ago.  Devices are connected, then, for no reason, they get disconnected.  When I try and reconnect, I can't get an IP.  When I check the Pi-hole server, I get no responses. The wifi router is fine, but the DHCP is down.  When I restart the Pi-hole servers, I can connect again, but only temporarily until the devices get disconnected.  I will continue troubleshooting and report back what I find.

PG

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/130816)